# Code Coverage for c# Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, testing, portable-class-library

I've got a C# Portable Class Library (which can be used by WinPhone, Win Store App, Silverlight etc.) covered with some tests.
I'd like to run that tests with built-in VS 2012 test environment and then get the code coverage results. But I don't get any results.

What's the reason?
How can I get the code coverage results?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to run code coverage analysis from VS 2012

see documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx

Comment: This is strange. It didn't work several days ago. It works now.
Thanks any way and sorry for dumb question!